# Asus N580vd with Ubuntu 16.04 freezes when I shut down it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, shutdown

I have an asus n580vd laptop which has dual graphics cards Nvidia 1050 and intel  R 630. I have installed ubuntu 16.04 but everytime I shutdown or restart, ubuntu freezes and I have to shutdown the system by pressing power button manually. I suspect that this might have to do with graphics cards drivers not installed. Could anyone please tell me how I can install appropriate driver(s) so that I can use my intel and nvidia graphics cards properly.

Thanks

Comment: "XY Problem" you should diagnose your problem before picking a solution (to some other problem) out of the ether.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved finally!

I used these instructions: [Switch Between Intel and Nvidia Graphics Card on Ubuntu.](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu)

First you need to install the driver that is suitable for your system. It will be recommended by asking in Ubuntu terminal. Then you choose the graphic card you want; for me, Nvidia.

Run

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and see which driver shows up as recommended, then install the recommended driver using `sudo apt install <package-name>`

After that, you can check **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** and make sure the new driver is being used.